# How can you add commits to a github pull request of another person to your repo if you can't commit to their branch?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Here's the scenario:

I have a public repo **A**. *Bob* forks **A**, adds a few commits to `Bob/master` and submits a pull request to merge those changes in `A/master`. I'd like to make a few changes to the proposed pull request before merging it back to `A/master`.

How can I do that if I can't push to `Bob/master`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a number of workflows you can use here. Some examples are:

1. Comment on the pull request, and have Bob make some changes. See [Pull Request Discussion](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/) for more info.
2. Merge the pull request onto a *different* branch, then make your changes before merging to master. You need to do this from the command line; see [Merging a Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/) for step-by-step instructions.
3. Edit the patch before applying it with `git am`. See [Patch and Apply](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/). This is probably the most flexible option, but also the most manual.

   ```
   git checkout master
   curl http://github.com/<username>/<project_name>/pull/<patch_number>.patch
   sensible-editor <patchfile>
   git am <patchfile>
   git push origin master
   ```

Comment: No ideal, but works, I specially like option 1. With option 3, I would take credit for Bob's commits, right?

Comment: Follow-on question moved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066980/who-gets-credit-for-a-hand-edited-patch-file

Comment: For more involved changes, there's no need to edit the patch by hand. After applying the patch with `git am` you can edit the repo files directly and then commit them with the `--amend` flag.

Comment: How do you (the repository owner) update the pull request with changes so the original author (of the pull request) can review the changes before you merge them with master?

Answer (score 2):

You can just pull from his branch on your local repo (not inside the github gui)

```
# make same work-in-progress branch and check it out
$ git checkout -b WIP

# pull his changes into WIP
$ git pull https://github.com/... master
```

and then mercilessly change from there on.

The other option would be to use github's comment system to talk him into changing his patchset (that way he could also keep the credit after the merge).

Comment: Isn't there any way that we both can keep credit? a way so that his and my commits appear listed under the pull request...

Comment: If you make commits and then merge his commits, don't all commits get preserved from a credit perspective?

Comment: @gregturn: If you change a commit the author gets changed, but does stay the original value if you just cherry-pick a commit.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make a PR into `Bob/master` containing your revisions. Bob can merge your PR into `Bob/master`; when you merge Bob's PR into `A/master`, it will contain Bob's commits and your commits.

You can create a PR from any fork/branch to any other fork/branch. So if Bob submits a PR from `Bob/feature`, just create a PR into `Bob/feature`.