# Why do we have to add the "HEAD:" prefix when pushing to a contributor's fork of a GitHub repo?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

My question is related to the discussion in [Contributing to an existing pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191350/3873510).

Gajus explained that GitHub [made it possible](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork) for repo owners to edit a a contributor's PR by pushing commits directly to the PR branch on their fork.

That's good. But as part of his explanation, there was this command in the terminal:

```bash
git push contributor-origin HEAD:branch-name
```

Why do we have to add the `HEAD:` prefix in front of the branch name for this to work? I tried pushing directly to `branch-name` but I got this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to REPO
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git push upstream x:y` simply says "on `upstream`, push my commit `x` to branch `y`".

`git push upstream branch-name` is a shortcut for `git push upstream branch-name:branch-name`.

You will get the error message you mention if the commit `x` you push is not a fast forward of `y`.

---

In the situation you describe, it so happened that :

- at the time you ran `git push upstream HEAD:branch`, your active commit was ahead of `branch`,
- at the time you ran `git push upstream branch`, your local branch wasn't ahead of its remote counterpart.

Run `git fetch upstream` and inspect how `upstream/branch` evolved.

Comment: Very well expressed.